# How to display user location If i can already display current weather? (Android)

Tags: android, location, weather, weather-api, openweathermap

I can get the current weather temperature from the users last known location and display it in a textview. How can I also display the user location that i am getting the weather information for? I am using OpenWeather for my API.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String APP_ID = "80e4eede56844462ef3cdc721208c31f";

    private static final int PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // All good!
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Need your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (googleApiClient != null) {
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Connected to Google Play Services");

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

            double lat = lastLocation.getLatitude(), lon = lastLocation.getLongitude();
            String units = "imperial";
            String url = String.format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%f&lon=%f&units=%s&appid=%s",
                    lat, lon, units, APP_ID);
            new GetWeatherTask(textView).execute(url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Can't connect to Google Play Services!");
    }

    private class GetWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Double> {
        private TextView textView;


        public GetWeatherTask(TextView textView) {
            this.textView = textView;
        }

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(Object... strings) {

            double weather = 0;

            try {
                URL url = new URL((String) strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                String inputString;
                while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(inputString);
                }

                JSONObject topLevel = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                JSONObject main = topLevel.getJSONObject("main");
                weather = main.getDouble("temp");


                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return weather;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Double temp) {
                textView.setText("Weather temperature is " + temp);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Um, put the location in a `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%f&lon=%f&appid=%s` api instead to get all the information about place including name,temp etc.

For place name: You have to extract JSON data as:

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(response) //the resp you are getting
String placeName = js.getString("name")
```

Like this you can extract many more details about the place.

**EDIT:** With this api you can get temperature as:

```
double temp = js.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp")
```

For setting the value to the textView, you can use:

```
TextView tw1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x) //Your textView's id
tw1.setText(placeName)
```

For setting double:
    tw1.setText(String.valueOf(temp));

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, when i use that link without changing anything else besides it, the temperature is showing up as 0.0.

Comment: You have to work in new format, as returned data is different compared to what you were getting before

Comment: Is there a way that i can just use the same link and format that i have to get just the city of the location?

Comment: I have edited the post for getting temperature with this api, try that and tell me the result

Comment: Which line? and can't you see changes in post?

Comment: Where do i put this line: double temp = js.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp") and no i don't see your post changes..

Comment: Just put all the three described code lines just after you are getting response, one variable would give you the temperature and the other is giving place name @JohnDoe

Comment: Edited to set the value in a textView, Please have a look and mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem, else explain what do you want to do with api and placename etc @JohnDoe